# Renaming N to N table in Code First EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two tables that are connect N to N:

```
[Table("Backoffice_Roles")]
public class Role
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}


[Table("Backoffice_Users")]
public class User
{
    // Primary key
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

This all works fine and it creates 3 tables: `Backoffice_Roles`, `Backoffice_Users` and `RoleUsers`.

Is there a way to rename `RoleUsers` to `Backoffice_RoleUsers` ?

I tried renaming the table manually in the migration file but it gives this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for
>   their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null
>   because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the
>   exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by
>   exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the
>   InnerException for details. --->
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while
>   updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name
>   'dbo.RoleUsers'.

This the migration without changing the name of the last table manually:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Backoffice_Users",
        c => new
            {
                UserId = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserId);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Backoffice_Roles",
        c => new
            {
                RoleId = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.RoleId);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.RoleUsers",
        c => new
            {
                Role_RoleId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                User_UserId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Role_RoleId, t.User_UserId })
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Backoffice_Roles", t => t.Role_RoleId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Backoffice_Users", t => t.User_UserId)
        .Index(t => t.Role_RoleId)
        .Index(t => t.User_UserId);

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following mapping to provide name for junction table:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
            .HasMany(r => r.Users)
            .WithMany(u => u.Roles)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("Backoffice_RoleUsers"));
```

You can provide mappings by overriding `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext` class.